# Can I optimize this code with an array for it to work on 100 pages in a single loop?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm fairly new in writing code in Python. I'm trying website parser with Beautiful Soup and it works fine.
I need guidance in making my code more optimized because I need to parse 100 pages of a single website one by one, and wanted to do it with a single loop + array of pages.
Pages change just by numbers like: https://www.example.com/cat?page1 /cat?page2 /cat?page3 and etc.
Please see the code below and please give advice if you can regarding my subject.
Thanks a lot in advance <3

```html
from __future__ import print_function
from re import sub
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
urlpage= urlopen("https://www.example.com/cat?page1").read()
bswebpage=BeautifulSoup(urlpage)
results=bswebpage.findAll("div",{'class':"someDiv"})
for result in results:
  print(sub("&ldquo;|.&rdquo;","","".join(result.contents[0:1]).strip()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a loop there like this:

```
for i in range(1, 101): #goes from 1-100
    url = f"https://www.example.com/cat?page{i}" #page1 etc.
    urlpage= urlopen(url).read()
    bswebpage=BeautifulSoup(urlpage)
    results=bswebpage.findAll("div",{'class':"someDiv"})
    for result in results: print(sub("&ldquo;|.&rdquo;","","".join(result.contents[0:1]).strip()))
```

The results part you can make an array:

```
all_results = []
(... then inside the for)
    all_results.append(results)
```